# errors Kendo UI Professional type Scripts

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, typescript

I added Kendo UI Professional type Scripts to my ASP MVC Project and then a lot of errors appear like:

> Build: Duplicate identifier 'action'
>
> Duplicate overload signature for 'kendo.dataviz.ui.plugin'

Comment: Adding some of your code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you have added two files that both define the same types.

I would have said that you have two different libraries that both place the type `action` in the same common root - but the second type seems highly unlikely to be repeated in multiple libraries, so it is more likely you have added type information twice.

This may have been caused by adding two definitions that both have `kendo.dataviz.ui.plugin` defined, or the same definition twice. For example - if you copy/pasted the type information, you might have accidentally pasted twice into the same file.

Do a "find all" with `kendo.dataviz.ui.plugin` to see if you have multiple declarations for it.